# Java cannot resolve symbol 'Maps'

Tags: java, gson, guava

I am trying to get a diff between two JSON files using gson and guava library in java.

I get the error: "cannot resolve symbol 'Maps'. I have the guava library jar file in lib folder in my InteliJ installation folder and dependency in pom.xml file looks like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
```

The function to create diff looks like this

```
public static Map<String, Object> newCompare(JsonElement original, JsonElement output){
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();

    Map<String, Object> leftMap = gson.fromJson(original, type);
    Map<String, Object> rightMap = gson.fromJson(output, type);
    return Maps.Difference(leftMap, rightMap);
}
```

I tried to reimport all maven projects and looked for an answer but all solutions I found were about android maps.
Can you give me some advice on how to solve this problem, or suggest any other solution? thank you a lot.

Comment: The error message and the code you posted don't seem to be related. There is no symbol `maps` in the code you posted, there is only `Maps` (Capitalization matters in programming). Is that a typo you made when you posted the question?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry it was a typo in the text part but the one in code is all right with capital letter. 
Thanks

Comment: 1. if you have the dependency as a maven dependency, then you shouldn't need the entry in the pom file (or add the systempath if you insist on using the local version). 2. do you have the required `import` for the fully qualified name of the class?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's [`Maps::difference`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#difference(java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map)) in Google's Guava, not `Maps::Difference` (usually, we never use *PascalCase* for method names in Java; rather *camelCase* is best convention).

Secondly, as of [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902134/java-cannot-resolve-symbol-maps/69902242#comment123566019_69902242), I've reproduced your problem by having same dependency:

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

and importing

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
```

after which,

```java
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

Maps.difference(map1, map2);
```

works just fine.

Comment: Thank you, this is for sure a mistake I would find later, but unfortunately in this case the problem is not in the name of used method, but in the Maps class that is not being recognized.

Comment: @timotej97 see updated answer.